# ConnectivityPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I installed the latest Flutter and dart and Android Studio. I have login page before login I checked internet available or not using connectivity plugin.

when running `flutter run` application working well.

when running `flutter build apk` after that running `flutter install` this warning message coming and always saying not connect to the internet

**Full issue report to GitHub**

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31834

> **SOLVED add this to the release mode android manifest**
>
> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing much you can do. As the `Warning` itself says that use of deprecated API in java code. Then, either you fix that and create a pull request on Github. or request Plugin Authors to fix that.